Sombody stole my meme coin name and image before I create a market ID
I was following Baird Business's 'I Made a Million Dollar Meme Coin In 1 Hour' tutorial on YouTube and created my meme coin. However, I realized it didn't work how he showed guidelines. What I did to creat coin was created a token on Orion tools and I got the token in my Phantom wallet however I couldn't find my token on birdeye.so with my token ID. So I waited a few moments to go on to the next step which is creating a market ID. About one hour later I noticed somebody put CA on my meme coin telegram group chat and I thought who put this and went on birdeye.so and typed the CA. It looked the same as my meme coin name, symbol, image except for the different supply numbers, decimals, token ID. And I assumed somebody copied my idea and created market before me. Is is a common scam? Does anybody know how to solve this problem?
